# Call RPC/Literal WSDL file from Android

Tags: android, wsdl, rpc

I would like to call [this WSDL file](http://www.danica.com.ar/recetario/recetario.wsdl) in android to retrieve data .

This is RPC/Literal WSDL structure but I can not able to parse it. I have parsed SOAP based normal WSDL file.

Please help me to solve this problem.

**Code:**

```
    import java.io.StringReader;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class WebServiceRecetrioActivity extends Activity 
{  
    Button btnReg;
    EditText fullName,emailId,password,confirmPwd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_main);

        btnReg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regId);
        fullName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        emailId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailId);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        confirmPwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pwd1);

        btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String xmlString = "http://www.danica.com.ar/recetario/recetario.wsdl"; //Added your wsdl as an xml string here

                try {
                     XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                     XmlPullParser pullParser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
                     pullParser.setInput(new StringReader(xmlString));

                     int eventType = pullParser.getEventType();
                     while (true) 
                     {
                        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                        {
                           String Tag = pullParser.getName();
                           System.out.println(Tag);

                        } 

                        else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                                break;
                        eventType = pullParser.next();
                     }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Exceptions:**

```
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT http://www.danic...@1:50 in java.io.StringReader@41223d10) 
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:426)
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767):  at com.webservice.WebServiceRecetrioActivity$1.onClick(WebServiceRecetrioActivity.java:62)
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-07 16:39:52.297: W/System.err(767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 16:39:52.307: W/System.err(767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 16:39:52.307: W/System.err(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-07 16:39:52.317: W/System.err(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 16:39:52.317: W/System.err(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 16:39:52.327: W/System.err(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-07 16:39:52.327: W/System.err(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-07 16:39:52.327: W/System.err(767):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have used `ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Answer (score 1):

Use [ksoapxml](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) library. It has the xml pull parser which you can use.

```
String xmlString = ""; //Added your wsdl as an xml string here

try {
            XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser pullParser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
            pullParser.setInput(new StringReader(xmlString));

            int eventType = pullParser.getEventType();




               while (true) 
               {
                   if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                   {
                       String Tag = pullParser.getName();

                       System.out.println(Tag);

                   } 

                   else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                       break;
                   eventType = pullParser.next();
               }
```

The output was as follows:

```
definitions
types
schema
complexType
all
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
complexType
all
element
element
element
element
element
complexType
sequence
element
complexType
sequence
element
complexType
all
element
element
element
element
element
element
complexType
sequence
element
complexType
all
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
element
complexType
sequence
element
complexType
all
element
element
element
element
element
element
message
part
message
part
message
part
part
message
part
message
part
part
message
part
part
part
message
part
message
part
message
part
message
part
message
part
message
part
message
part
part
message
part
portType
operation
input
output
operation
input
output
operation
input
output
operation
input
output
operation
input
output
operation
input
output
operation
input
output
binding
soap:binding
operation
soap:operation
input
soap:body
output
soap:body
operation
soap:operation
input
soap:body
output
soap:body
operation
soap:operation
input
soap:body
output
soap:body
operation
soap:operation
input
soap:body
output
soap:body
operation
soap:operation
input
soap:body
output
soap:body
operation
soap:operation
input
soap:body
output
soap:body
operation
soap:operation
input
soap:body
output
soap:body
service
documentation
port
soap:address

HttpClient httpCLient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serverUrl);
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

Pass the result to your parser.

Get list of all attributes and values for each tag

```
int count = pullParser.getAttributeCount();
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
Log.d("App", pullParser.getAttributeName(i) + ":" + pullParser.getAttributeValue(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have know about this library . This is RPC/Literal webservice. Can you please provide code regarding this.

Comment: Using this code can I parse data from this WSDL ? I will +1 for your answer and if your answer fulfill my requirement then I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have used ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar this. Is this right choice to do this or anything else? If any thing else then please provide a suitable link

Comment: Rather user the updated version ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar - URl - ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.1.1/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Hey You code gives exception. I will post my code with exception.

Comment: I have posted my code + exceptions . Please look at this and give me some some solutions.

Comment: The comment in the code where it says add your wsdl string here means the actual xml returned by the wsdl string and not the url.

Comment: It will be hectic process to place a large WSDL file here. I would like to use URL , so what is the way to do this. Please suggest.

Comment: is there any way to call from URL?

Comment: Use an async task to do a get request to your url and read the responsebody and parse it into a string and then you can send that string to the parser.

Comment: can you please provide code for this. It will be really help me.

Comment: I have put hardcore WSDL and it gives the output exactly your given output. So, after that what is the procedure to get value from server?

Comment: You need to loop through the Attributes and can get their values. I suggest taking a look at some of the examples of xmlpullparser.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will search this, but can you please a provide a small code to fetch single value through attribute from server? Please help me.

Comment: I have post a question regarding this topics-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252369/rpc-literal-wsdl-does-not-fetch-values-from-android please suggest me

Comment: it gives argument list, but does not able to fetch value from server. Through SOAP how I will do this? Please share your knowledge.