# RPC/Literal WSDL does not fetch values from Android

Tags: java, android, wsdl

My Java code:

```
    import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String txtName, txtEmail, txtPassword, txtConfPassword;
    TextView nameView, emailView, passView, confPassView;
    private XMLRPCClient client;
    private URI uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class RegistrarionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*
             * XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient(
             * "http://www.danica.com.ar/recetario/recetario.wsdl");
             * Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
             * vector.addElement(txtName); vector.addElement(txtEmail);
             * vector.addElement(txtPassword); Object result = null; try {
             * result = client.execute("Registration", vector);
             * 
             * } catch (Exception e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             * e.printStackTrace(); }
             */

            uri = URI
                    .create("http://www.danica.com.ar/recetario/recetario.wsdl");
            client = new XMLRPCClient(uri);
            String result = null;
            try {
                // result = (String) client.call("Registration");
                result = (String) client.call("Registration", txtName,
                        txtEmail, txtPassword);

            } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {

            }

        }
    }

    public void onRegisterClick(View v) {

        nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        nameView.requestFocus();
        emailView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        passView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        confPassView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConfPass);

        txtName = nameView.getText().toString().trim();
        txtEmail = emailView.getText().toString().trim();
        txtPassword = passView.getText().toString().trim();
        txtConfPassword = confPassView.getText().toString().trim();

        if (txtName.equals("")) {
            nameView.setError("This field is required!");
            nameView.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (txtEmail.equals("")) {
            emailView.setError("This field is required!");
            emailView.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!txtEmail.contains("@")) {
            emailView.setError("Not a valid Email!");
            emailView.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (txtPassword.equals("")) {
            passView.setError("This field is required!");
            passView.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!txtPassword.equals(txtConfPassword)) {
            confPassView.setError("Not a matching password!");
            confPassView.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        new RegistrarionTask().execute();
    }

}
```

and XML layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtConfPass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Confirm Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:onClick="onRegisterClick"
    android:text="Register" />
```

But when I have run this code it gives exception this:

```
    03-07 19:30:59.537: W/System.err(1016): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}methodResponse (position:START_TAG <definitions name='Recetario' targetNamespace='http://danica.com.ar/recetario' xmlns:tns='http://danica.com.ar/recetario' xmlns:xsd1='http://danica.com.ar/recetarioNamespace' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap-enc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>@9:43 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4122e1f8) 
03-07 19:30:59.537: W/System.err(1016):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
03-07 19:30:59.537: W/System.err(1016):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:200)
03-07 19:30:59.537: W/System.err(1016):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.call(XMLRPCClient.java:314)
03-07 19:30:59.537: W/System.err(1016):     at com.example.kousikchatterjee.MainActivity$RegistrarionTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:59)
03-07 19:30:59.537: W/System.err(1016):     at com.example.kousikchatterjee.MainActivity$RegistrarionTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
03-07 19:30:59.547: W/System.err(1016):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-07 19:30:59.547: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-07 19:30:59.547: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-07 19:30:59.547: W/System.err(1016):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-07 19:30:59.547: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-07 19:30:59.547: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-07 19:30:59.547: W/System.err(1016):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-07 19:30:59.557: W/System.err(1016): org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}methodResponse (position:START_TAG <definitions name='Recetario' targetNamespace='http://danica.com.ar/recetario' xmlns:tns='http://danica.com.ar/recetario' xmlns:xsd1='http://danica.com.ar/recetarioNamespace' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap-enc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>@9:43 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4122e1f8) 
03-07 19:30:59.557: W/System.err(1016):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:237)
03-07 19:30:59.557: W/System.err(1016):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.call(XMLRPCClient.java:314)
03-07 19:30:59.579: W/System.err(1016):     at com.example.kousikchatterjee.MainActivity$RegistrarionTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:59)
03-07 19:30:59.579: W/System.err(1016):     at com.example.kousikchatterjee.MainActivity$RegistrarionTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
03-07 19:30:59.579: W/System.err(1016):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-07 19:30:59.579: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-07 19:30:59.587: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-07 19:30:59.587: W/System.err(1016):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-07 19:30:59.587: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-07 19:30:59.597: W/System.err(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-07 19:30:59.597: W/System.err(1016):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-07 19:30:59.607: W/System.err(1016): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}methodResponse (position:START_TAG <definitions name='Recetario' targetNamespace='http://danica.com.ar/recetario' xmlns:tns='http://danica.com.ar/recetario' xmlns:xsd1='http://danica.com.ar/recetarioNamespace' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap-enc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>@9:43 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4122e1f8) 
03-07 19:30:59.607: W/System.err(1016):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
03-07 19:30:59.617: W/System.err(1016):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:200)
03-07 19:30:59.617: W/System.err(1016):     ... 10 more
```

Please provide me solve code on the basis of my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suffered from last seven days. For this reason I have posted the question, when I have posted at that time I have no idea about WSDL and SOAP . Here is the solve answer by me :

**Code:**

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RecetarionDanica extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://danica.com.ar/recetario/Registration";
    //private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://danica.com.ar/recetario";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "Registration";
    //private static String METHOD_NAME2 = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String URL = "http://danica.com.ar/cgi-bin/soapserver.pl";

    Button btnReg;
    EditText fullName,emailId,password,confirmPwd;
    String result="";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_main);

        btnReg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regId);
        fullName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        emailId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailId);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        confirmPwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pwd1);

        btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //Initialize soap request + add parameters
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);                
                Log.d("request", request.toString());
                //Use this to add parameters
                User user = new User();

                user.setEmail(""+emailId.getText().toString().trim());
                user.setFirstName(""+fullName.getText().toString().trim());
                user.setPassword(""+password.getText().toString().trim());
                user.setGplusId(" ");//(""+fullName.getText().toString().trim());
                user.setTweet(" ");//(""+fullName.getText().toString().trim());
                user.setLastName(" ");//(""+fullName.getText().toString().trim());
                user.setFacebookId(" ");//(""+fullName.getText().toString().trim());

                request.addProperty("user", user);

//              request.addProperty("email",emailId.getText().toString().trim());
//              request.addProperty("firstName",fullName.getText().toString().trim());              
//              request.addProperty("password",password.getText().toString().trim());
                Log.d("request 2", request.toString());
                //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  
                //envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "user", new User.getClass());

                Log.d("envelope", envelope.toString());

                try {

                    Log.d("TRY Block", "TRY");
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    Log.d("androidHttpTransport", androidHttpTransport.toString());
                    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    Log.d("---Block---", "Block 2");

                    SoapObject result = null;
                    if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                        String str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                        Log.i("Fault", str);

                    } else {
                        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.               
                        result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                        Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(result));
                    }

                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        //Get the first property and change the label text
                        Log.d("If result not null", String.valueOf(result));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });        

    }
}
```

**For complexType WSDL**

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;

public class User implements KvmSerializable {
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String password;
    private String gplusId ;
    private String tweeterId ;
    private String lastName;
    private String facebookId;

public User() {}

public User(String email, String firstName, String password, String gplus, String tweet, String lastName, String facebook) {
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.password = password;
    this.gplusId = gplus;
    this.tweeterId = tweet;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.facebookId = facebook;
}

public User(String email, String firstName, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.password = password;
}

public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }
public void setGplusId(String gplusId) { this.gplusId = gplusId; }
public void setTweet(String tweeterId) { this.tweeterId = tweeterId; }
public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) { this.facebookId = facebookId; }



public String getEmail() { return email;}
public String getFirstName() { return firstName;}
public String getPassword() { return password;}
public String getGplusId() { return gplusId;}
public String getTweet() { return tweeterId;}
public String getLastName() { return lastName;}
public String getFacebookId() { return facebookId;}

public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch(arg0) {
        case 0:
            return email;
        case 1:
            return firstName;
        case 2:
            return password;
        case 3:
            return gplusId;
        case 4:
            return tweeterId;
        case 5:
            return lastName;
        case 6:
            return facebookId;
     }
     return null;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 7;
}

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
            propertyInfo.name = "email";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case 1:
            propertyInfo.name = "firstName";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case 2:
            propertyInfo.name = "password";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case 3:
            propertyInfo.name = "gplusId";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case 4:
            propertyInfo.name = "tweeterId";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case 5:
            propertyInfo.name = "lastName";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        case 6:
            propertyInfo.name = "facebookId";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index) {
        case 0:
            this.email = value.toString();
            break;
        case 1:
            this.firstName = value.toString();
            break;
        case 2:
            this.password = value.toString();
            break;
        case 3:
            this.gplusId = value.toString();
            break;
        case 4:
            this.tweeterId = value.toString();
            break;
        case 5:
            this.lastName = value.toString();
            break;
        case 6:
            this.facebookId = value.toString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
   }
}
}
```

**UI Layout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email id"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwd1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/regId"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to give permission `INTERNET` in `AndroidManifest.xml` .